# how to render columns in laravel datatable?

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

i'm got stuck for 2 days, i got confused how to render column usind yajra/laravel-datatable

i'm using `postgre` as database, and `yajra/laravel-datatables` as package.

i have query builder like this

```
$data = DB::select("SELECT * FROM get_list_count_amount_transaction('chat', 'done', '2019-03-01', '2021-12-31' )")[0];
```

which generates a value of object : (i use `var_dump()` to see the value)

```
{ ["list_data"]=> string(2171) 
    "[{"id":"44649ccd-9195-4964-b48c-ed2098077dc5","kd_join":1,"status":"done","booking_date":"2021-04-18","transaction_type":"chat","price":4000.00,"date_create":"2021-04-18T19:56:57"},
      {"id":"e500d2c1-99ae-4436-8ecc-8073f4f05bba","kd_join":1,"status":"done","booking_date":"2021-03-20","transaction_type":"chat","price":10000.00,"date_create":"2021-03-19T21:41:41"}
     ]"
  ["count_transaction"]=> int(12) 
  ["total_amount_transaction"]=> string(9) "160500.00" 
}
```

i'm confused, how to render `list_data` into a table using datatble

this is my html builder function :

```
    public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
            ->columns($this->getColumns())

            ->minifiedAjax()
            ->addAction(['width' => '200px'])
            ->addColumnBefore([
                'defaultContent' => '',
                'data' => 'DT_Row_Index',
                'name' => 'DT_Row_Index',
                'title' => 'No',
                'render' => function () {
                    return 'function(data,type,fullData,meta){return meta.settings._iDisplayStart+meta.row+1;}';
                },
                'orderable' => false,
                'searchable' => false,
                'exportable' => false,
                'printable' => true,
                'footer' => '',
            ]);
    }

    protected function getColumns()
    {
        return [
            ['data' => 'transaction_type', 'name' => 'transaction_type', 'title' => 'Tipe Transaksi', 'orderable' => false],
            ['data' => 'status', 'name' => 'status', 'title' => 'Status', 'orderable' => false],
            ['data' => 'booking_date', 'name' => 'booking_date', 'title' => 'Tanggal Booking', 'orderable' => false],
            ['data' => 'price', 'name' => 'price', 'title' => 'Jumlah', 'orderable' => false],
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: You dont need to use the html builder. https://datatables.yajrabox.com/collection/basic

Comment: but how to render only value on ```list_data```?

Comment: still got error :(

Comment: The var_dump result you provided shows that `list_data` contains a string. It seems your data is saved as JSON. To use it you can do something with [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php): `$listDataArray = json_decode($data["list_data"]);`

Comment: i have already doing that, but still got internal sever error in my console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just grab the list_data, use json_decode and laravel collection to make your needed structure. Try to use `map`, `filter`, `mapWithKeys` or whatever suitable.
For Instance:

```
collect(json_decode($listData))->mapWithKeys(function($item)){

      //
}
```